Taskbar XML Configuration not applying via Group Policy
I've been struggling to succesfully add pins to user taskbars via GPO through applying an XML config file via Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar after following the instructions from Microsoft.
The path is reachable by the client and the policy is being applied as shown by GPRESULT /R
My XML is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook.lnk"/>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
 </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>


It turns out that Microsoft's example is not XML valid as they forgot to close out the <taskbar:TaskbarPinList> tag
Add  </taskbar:TaskbarPinList> after   <taskbar:TaskbarPinList> and then add what you want to pin in between that.
